# Dynamic conditions in SQL where clause by passing parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I have a SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @sy VARCHAR(10)
set @sy='>'

select EM.EmpId,EM.EmpName,ETR.Rating as Rating,
from [dbo].[EmploeeMaster_Data] as EM
join [dbo].[EmpTechRating_Data] as ETR on EM.EmpId=ETR.Emp_id
where EM.CompetencyId in (2,5) and ETR.Rating > 1
```

In the where condition ETR.Rating > 1, I want to place '>' with a parameter @sy,
@sy values will be like '>','=','<','>=' etc, based on @sy I want to put condition. I tried putting case and IF conditions in where clause

```
where EM.CompetencyId in (2,5) and Case @sy when '>' ETR.Rating > 1
when '<' ETR.Rating < 1
when '=' ETR.Rating = 1
END
```

But it is giving a syntax error, can anyone help me out, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a case statement to change the operator.

You would need to write it like this:

```
AND (
    (@sy = '>' AND ETR.Rating > 1)
 OR (@sy = '<' AND ETR.Rating < 1)
 OR (@sy = '>=' AND ETR.Rating >= 1)
 OR (@sy = '<=' AND ETR.Rating <= 1)
    /* ETC...*/
    )
```